# Why are 10.3(99w)F and 10.3(99x)F NX-OS named like that?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus, cisco-nx-os

According to https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/ios-nx-os-software/nx-os-software/guide_c07-658595.html#TypesofCiscoNXOSSoftwarereleases the part in brackets - "99w" and "99x" in these releases is supposed to be sequantial release number.

The question is why is there "99" and not "4", since previous version is "10.3(3)F" released on 08/May/2023, and what is "w" and "x" letters in them? There's no clarification on this on release pages or on Lifecycle support page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation from Cisco says:

> Cisco NX-OS Release 10.3(99x)F is special software version to introduce BGP EVPN VXLAN with IPv6 Multicast in the Underlay. Before implementing, we STRONGLY advise to discuss with your Cisco Sales Representative for further guidance and assistance.

> Cisco NX-OS Release 10.3(99w)F is special software version to introduce BGP EVPN VXLAN with IPv6 Multicast in the Underlay. Before implementing, we STRONGLY advise to discuss with your Cisco Sales Representative for further guidance and assistance.

I haven't seen any other release for Nexus that has that naming format with an 'x' in the version so I would assume that is the reason. There are other 10.4 releases for hardware models that use the 10.3(99X)F release that do not have the 'x' so it would be important to work with Cisco support to determine which is the right version to use if you want the BGP EVPN VXLAN feature set. The release with 'w' in the name would be a previous release of the same software and feature set. The 'x' release is probably a bug fix version of the same.